# wpf BitmapImage loaded at wrong dpi

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmapimage

I'm loading a png with the following

```
  imageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Resources/types/ActiveWord.png"));
```

The properties of the png are 32, 32 @ 96 DPI (confirmed with Paint)
However the BitmapImage sets the Dpi to 150.

Why is BitmapImage changing the dpi?

Other posts on here suggest that WPF defaults to 96 dpi.

Comment: That's probably because the image in your application resources is 150 dpi, not 96 dpi as you believe... Are you sure that the PNG image inside your application resources is not 150 dpi? Extract the image from the application and check its DPI setting. Do not rely on checking whatever source image you are using. To me it seems you either made a mistake while verifying the dpi, or some processing / custom build step when building your application changed the dpi setting of the image...

Comment: well when I examine the image with MS Paint it says the dpi is 96 which I then import into my app. Is there a way to examine the resource?

Comment: @elgonzo looks like you were correct, paint is incorrectly reporting the resolution.

Comment: Now, don't tell me it's the the Paint app of *Windows 10*... ;-)